# Integrate jenkins to Power BI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

How can I integrate Jenkins to POWERBI, i.e, getting jenkins jobs build and failed And JOb NUMBERS to POWERBI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thing there is a direct way of doing it currently.
(https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/6798689-jenkins-data-source)

But as a workaround you can always create a groovy script to read jenkins log and use database to store data.
From there you can use powerBI to create reports.